# Is it possible to go outside during my three-hour transit in Brussels?

Tags: transit, layovers, brussels, bru

My flight from Rwanda to Russia through Brussels. I will have 4 hours transit in Brussels airport. Can I enjoy my connection time outside of the airport till time approaches?

Answer (score 3):

The practicalities of traveling to the city centre are covered in [Are 7 hours enough time to leave the Brussels airport and go to the city center?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14621/are-7-hours-enough-time-to-leave-the-brussels-airport-and-go-to-the-city-center)

The only problem left (or not, considering that 3 hours is really short) is whether it's allowed at all. This will depend on your citizenship. If you are a citizen of either Rwanda or Russia, you won't be allowed to leave the transit area of the airport without a visa. A full list of countries whose citizens can do it is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union#Visa_exemptions).